# Как в Гите настроить отдельную папку для просмотра истории проекта?

Tags: git

В итоге должна быть возможность параллельного просмотра истории проекта в отдельной папке, чтобы оттуда переносить необходимые данные в текущее состояние проекта.

Comment: Паралельный просмотр истории - это просто возможность смотреть историю в двух разных ветках одновременно?

Comment: что такое "снимки репозитория"? коммиты?

Comment: нет, просто @akp не знает, что git log <hahs/branc> можно смотреть с любой ветки для любой другой. Потом, зная хеш конкретного изменения, можно посмотреть его через git show, git cherry-pick поможет подтянуть. А то, что предлагает D-side - немного перегруженно

Comment: @0andriy например, `worktree` очень сильно помогают в том, чтобы мержить ветки в Unity3d. Там есть встроенный мерж-тул для сцен (сериализованных в YAML), но для него нужно прямо в редакторе перетащить один файл на другой.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, кто-то удалил изначальный комментарий. Я вроде бы вспомнил о чём речь... Спасибо за интересный случай использования. Но он скорее не про вопрос, а про ответ ниже. Я пользуюсь `git worktree` примерно с 2.6.

Comment: @0andriy вы там вроде писали, что автор хочет чего-то бесполезного. Вот вам пример, когда две копии проекта очень полезны. Хоть через worktree, хоть дважды клонированные.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не бесполезного а *очень странного*. Небольшая разница в словах всё-таки присутствует. ;) Как я уже сказал, спасибо за приведенный случай использования.

Comment: @0andriy пишу с телефона, удаленные комментарии не вижу. Пожалуйста. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### (Git 2.5.1+) [`git worktree add путь/к/папке ревизия`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)

`ревизия` может быть веткой, тегом, хэшем коммита или другим указателем (например `HEAD^`).

Чтобы "перемотать" историю, перейдите в ту папку и сделайте обычный `git checkout` на нужное вам место.

И вообще, работа в нём выглядит приблизительно так же, как в обычном Git-репозитории. У этого рабочего дерева собственный HEAD. Единственное существенное ограничение: нельзя сделать `checkout` одной и той же ветки в нескольких деревьях сразу. Точнее, можно, но в одном из них придётся использовать флаг `--detach`, и рабочее дерево реально будет указывать не на ветку, а на коммит, на котором она находится... но для чтения это неважно.

---

Для более старых версий Git проще всего клонировать репозиторий.

Comment: @akp предпочитаю ссылаться на оригинальные тексты за их точность.

Comment: @akp можете её не читать, делов-то. В ответе всё равно уже приведено всё необходимое.

Comment: Немного обобщил, если не возражаете.

Comment: А зачем клонировать, если можно просто скопировать папку? Будет быстрее.

Comment: @akp это вы не знаете английский, но довольно многие знают его достаточно, чтобы документацию понять. Им эта ссылка будет полезна. Ответ ведь не только вы читать будете, а ещё сотни и тысячи разных людей.

Comment: @NickVolynkin `git clone` с локальной папки фактически это и делает. Не принципиально.

Comment: @D-side да, но после клонирования с локальной папки нужно перенастраивать remote. Сложно, могут быть ошибки. )))

Comment: @NickVolynkin если клон нужен только для чтения (как здесь), то не нужно.

Comment: @D-side подумал ещё и понял, что не пришлось бы ничего перенастраивать. Можно и дальше обновлять сначала основной локальный, а потом из него остальные.

Comment: @NickVolynkin можете посмотреть на этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1008511/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8e про гит историю