# Как гит хранит историю? И как ее чистить?

Tags: git

Сегодня пришлось задуматься о том, как гит хранит историю?

Вопрос очень простой, скажем я создал проект, сложил в него очень тяжелые файлы(2 гб) и сделал коммит. Потом я эти файлы удалил и у меня и сделал еще коммит. Но я могу вернуться на предыдущий коммит и получить эти файлы обратно, верно? Значит из этого следует, что при удалении файлов, гит все равно хранит их копии, а значит вес проекта (самой папки) и занимаемое ей место при удалении тяжелых файлов не уменьшиться?

Но мне почему то **не** кажется, что когда я делаю клон ветки прокта, что я получаю всю историю (скажем прошлые коммиты и тяжелые файлы 2гб в нашем примере) во всяком случае локально в файлах на компе их нет.

Но ведь история коммитов у меня есть, а значит и все файлы должны быть сохранены(как то, где то)...

Короче, что то тут не сходиться.

Вопрос в том, действительно ли храняться все копии файлов? А если проекту 10 лет и за это время уже миллион файлов(и их вес) были удалены они, что до сих пор где то в гите храняться?

Comment: Гит хранит всё. Вся история (если специально не заморачиваться) есть в папке `.git`, но данные сжимаются и всячески оптимизируются, поэтому вы и не можете найти там свой файл.

Comment: А вообще ответ на вопрос в заголовке отлично находится гуглом

Comment: Есть хороший цикл статей о внутреннем устройстве git. Вот его компиляция на opennet: https://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/git_guts.txt.html

Comment: Вам бы понять разницу в инфинитивах возвратных глаголов в русском языке... А по теме, в индексе всё есть. Git компрессирует файлы, а также умеет работать со sparse-файлами, если я правильно помню.

Comment: Для удаления совсем старых и точно ненужных вещей (когда-то по ошибке впушенных бинарников, например) можно использовать BFG Repo-Cleaner: https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Гит все равно хранит их копии, а значит вес проекта (самой папки) и занимаемое ей место при удалении тяжелых файлов не уменьшиться

Да, верно. Проверим:

```
# так смотрим размер каталога .git
du -hs .git
# так можно сделать файл 1Мб
dd if=/dev/zero of=filename bs=1M count=1
```

- пустой проект 104 Кб
- после коммита файла `filename` в 1Мб вес `.git` 164 Кб (гит сжимает данные)
- после удаления файла `filename` и коммита - 180 Кб

> Но мне почему то не кажется, что когда я делаю клон ветки прокта, что я получаю всю историю

Это вам только кажется

> А если проекту 10 лет и за это время уже миллион файлов(и их вес) были удалены они, что до сих пор где то в гите храняться?

Да

## Как можно уменьшить размер `.git` каталога:

- запустить `git gc --aggressive`, но он пропылесосит только ненужные файлы, и пережмет данные, но файл `filename` так и останется в репо, но место освободилось: стало 152Кб
- переписать историю через `git rebase`: что-то удалить, что-то слить
- выкачивать репо без всей истории: `git clone --depth 1 ...` скачает историю на глубину 1

Для хранения больших файлов (мультимедиа) лучше использовать [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/)

## git gc

Это служебная команда оптимизации "базы данных гита". Какие-то объекты в этой базе становятся недостижимыми (столкнетесь при большем погружении в гит, они появляются при "переписывании истории") - они удаляются. Данные пережимаются, ведь индекс в процессе эксплуатации становится не совсем оптимальным, вот он и "перестраивается". С самим репозиторием, как это видно "внешне", при вызове `git gc` ничего не происходит, вся история остается на месте.

> если я локально чищу .git, то синхронизируются ли эти изменения с удаленным репо?

- через `git gc` - нет, эта команда для локального применения, она оптимизирует локальный репо, смысла делать ее перед `push` совершенно нет, удаленный репо имеет "свой мусор", и чистить удаленный репо можно только путем захода на удаленный сервер и запуска `git gc` в bare-репо
- если вы комитили, комитили, и наконец, **перед push** (это крайне важно!!!) решили сократить размер репо - используйте `git rebase`: путем объединения коммитов вы "почтистите историю" (в первом коммите огромный файл был, а во втором его удалили) - при пуше в удаленный репо этот огромный файл передаваться не будет, это главное. А в локальном репо размер `.git` после `rebase` вырастет - на "историю rebase". И тот огромный файл в каталоге `.git` также останется в виде сжатого объекта, хотя и недоступного (так как вы поменяли историю). А вот запуск `git gc` теперь удалит из `.git` этот файл и из вашего локального репо

> правда я так понимаю, что они не идентичны так как удалено находится bare repo

Правильно понимаете. А для распределённой системы управления версиями, которой является git, "клонированный" может быть точь-в-точь как "удаленный" только в момент клонирования. Дальше, по мере появления коммитов, на уровне байтов они начинают расходиться все больше. История может и будет совпдать, но каталог `.git` - нет. По сути `.git` - это база данных, и работать с ней нужно как с базой данных, а не на уровне файлов и байтов. `git gc` искусственно запускать также не нужно, git сам предложит это сделать, когда начнет работать медленно, и даже будет делать это самостоятельно, если стоит опция `gc.auto 1`.

Comment: `git gc --aggressive` у меня уменьшил размер в 2 раза, с 600 до 300 кб это не значительно, но все же... Но когда делаю `git status` я не вижу никаких изменений, значит я предполагаю, что при пуше в удаленом репо ничего не поменяется?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, это служебная команда оптимизации "базы данных гита". Какие-то объекты в этой базе становятся недостижимыми (столкнетесь при большем погружении в гит, они появляются при "переписывании истории") - они удаляются. Данные пережимаются, ведь индекс в процессе эксплуатации становится не совсем оптимальным, вот он и "перестраивается". С самим репозиторием, как это видно "внешне" - ничего не происходит. По гиту доступна справка через `man git`, по подкомандам - по принципу `man git-название-команды`. `man git-gc` в данном случае.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%A3%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85#r_git_gc

Comment: да, но я имел ввиду, что скажем у нас локально есть `.git` и удалено тоже есть `.git` (правда я так понимаю, что они не эдентичны так как удалено находиться `bare repo`) , так вот вопрос, если я локально чищу `.git` , то синхронизируются ли эти изменения с удаленным репо?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, дополнил ответ