# Git reflog, reset, checkout

Tags: linux, git

В результате экспериментов с Git получил вот такой мусор

```
$ git reflog
a40b147 (HEAD) HEAD@{0}: rebase -i (start): checkout HEAD~5
22955c2 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from efaf3c9de5dbdb0c441b8a1a90d895c6a0b4f766 to 22955c2
efaf3c9 HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from 22955c2b6ba1a444e001dfd9f3c768511e3053ef to efaf3c9
22955c2 HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to 22955c2
efaf3c9 HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to efaf3c9
c6b7a1a HEAD@{5}: reset: moving to c6b7a1a
faffd9a HEAD@{6}: reset: moving to faffd9a
27eeb50 (master) HEAD@{7}: reset: moving to 27eeb50
a40b147 (HEAD) HEAD@{8}: reset: moving to a40b147
27eeb50 (master) HEAD@{9}: checkout: moving from efaf3c9de5dbdb0c441b8a1a90d895c6a0b4f766 to 27eeb50
efaf3c9 HEAD@{10}: checkout: moving from a40b147dafda557495bf1f1ec597802c88cdaaa4 to efaf3c9
a40b147 (HEAD) HEAD@{11}: checkout: moving from efaf3c9de5dbdb0c441b8a1a90d895c6a0b4f766 to a40b147
efaf3c9 HEAD@{12}: checkout: moving from 62551ea08be4be95d857ee062ef1809905f5abf2 to efaf3c9
62551ea HEAD@{13}: checkout: moving from 22955c2b6ba1a444e001dfd9f3c768511e3053ef to HEAD~1
22955c2 HEAD@{14}: checkout: moving from master to 22955c2
27eeb50 (master) HEAD@{15}: commit: 29 Jan 2020-r3
efaf3c9 HEAD@{16}: reset: moving to HEAD~2
611e768 HEAD@{17}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
faffd9a HEAD@{18}: reset: moving to HEAD
faffd9a HEAD@{19}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/master
faffd9a HEAD@{20}: commit: 29 Jan 2020-r2
611e768 HEAD@{21}: commit (amend): 29 Jan 2020
f7f7070 HEAD@{22}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
a088f17 HEAD@{23}: rebase -i (start): checkout HEAD~6
c6b7a1a HEAD@{24}: commit: 29 Jan 2020
22955c2 HEAD@{25}: commit: 29 Jan 2020
62551ea HEAD@{26}: commit: 29 Jan 2020
a088f17 HEAD@{27}: commit: 29 Jan 2020
f7f7070 HEAD@{28}: commit: 28 Jan 2020
a40b147 (HEAD) HEAD@{29}: commit: 28 Jan 2020
efaf3c9 HEAD@{30}: commit (initial): Initial commit. Beggins
```

Как можно подчистить (удалить) лишнее?

И заметил такое, если я делаю `git reset --hard ...` до более ранней ветки, то окатить изменения более поздней не всегда работает.

Comment: Зачем подчищать? Место на диске экономить? Тогда `git gc --aggressive`. Но сначала `man git-gc`. `окатить изменения более поздней не всегда работает` - `git checkout sha-коммита` не работает?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1008511/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%98-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c/1008514#1008514

Comment: @TotalPusher, не, не место. просто смущает несколько (HEAD) ну и запутаться можно. Или это не критично? Скорее всего работает, просто редактор не всегда реагировал на изменения файла.

Comment: Они как-то вам мешают?

Comment: Если вы про это: `HEAD@{0}`, `HEAD@{1}`, `HEAD@{2}` - то это значит, что можно переключаться по `git checkout HEAD@{...}` - "путешествовать" по рефлогу. Тоже самое произойдет если указать sha коммита. Просто другой способ записи. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34519716/9435985